# Get posts by meta data OR title

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, get-posts

I have a *working* query that calls all my posts that have a certain meta value for one of two meta keys:

```
$term = filter_var( $_GET['term'] );
$query = get_posts( [
    'post_type' => 'some_cpt_name',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        [
            'key'     => 'foo',
            'value'   => $term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'bar',
            'value'   => $term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ]
] );
```

I need to query all posts that have the `$term` as meta key "foo" or "bar" or as post title. Problem is *how to* add the post title as additional possible key?

> **Q:** How can I *also* check if the `$term` maybe is in the `post_title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most questions involving `OR` clauses, the answer is the same: use a custom query or alter `WP_Query` using the `'posts_clauses'` filter.

Comment: Not really the answer as I was searching for the query string, but enough to be marked as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here's the final addition using the `posts_clauses` filter (and edit) as suggested from @scribu:

```
function alter_posts_where_clause( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $term = filter_var( trim( $_GET['term'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE );
    if ( is_null( $term ) )
        return $where;

    $term = $wpdb->esc_like( $term );

    // Append to the WHERE clause:
    $where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%s'", "%{$term}%" );

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'alter_posts_where_clause' );
```