# Creating an auto result search bar

Tags: ajax, wpdb

I'm trying to create a search bar that will show me titles of posts when the user types into the text field.

I'm completely new to this and I really don't know how to go about doing this. What would I do?

Here is the text input html element:

```
<input type='text' id='searchField' class='pushLeft tabRight hide' onKeyUp="autoSearch('<?php echo esc_js(site_url()); ?>')"/>
```

And here is the javascript, which I'd like to point out is in a folder called "js" and in that is my javascript file "general.js:"

```
function autoSearch(link)
{
    $("#searchResults").width($("#searchArea").width());
    if($("#searchField").val() != "")
    {
        $.post(link,{autoSearch:"", value:$("#searchField").val()},function(data){
            $("#searchResults").show();
            $("#searchResults").html(data.everything);
        },"json");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#searchResults").hide();
    }
}
```

Then in functions.php I have the following section of code:

```
isset( $_POST['autoSearch'] ) && add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_60353_autosearch' );
    function wpse_60353_autosearch()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $searchQuery = mysql_escape_string($_POST['value']);

        $mypostids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '$searchQuery' LIMIT 5");

        $args = array('post__in='.$mypostids);

        $res = new WP_Query($arg);  

        $titles ="";

        while ( $res->have_posts() ) : $res->the_post();
            $titles .= get_the_title().'<br />';
        endwhile;

        echo json_encode(array("everything"=>"hello"));

        wp_reset_postdata();

        exit; // All done, stop WP continuing
    }
```

I get a POST response saying this:

```
301 Moved Permanently
```

Comment: Something to read: [Very closely related Question A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete). [Something about `prepare()` and `like_escape()` in queries](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37517/385). --- Then there're the questions _where_, _how_ and _when_ you use the code you showed above. Could be that you're too early and `$wpdb;` isn't yet initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then "autoSearch.php" has this code:

If that's all there is, no wonder you get an error - WP isn't even loaded!

Add this to your `functions.php`

```
isset( $_POST['autoSearch'] ) && add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_60353_autosearch' );
function wpse_60353_autosearch()
{
    // The autoSearch.php code you posted in your question

    exit; // All done, stop WP continuing
}
```

Now just use the main URL for your AJAX request. The function will intercept the default WordPress runtime & return your data as expected.

```
$.post( "<?php echo esc_js( site_url() ) ?>" ...
```

Using this technique means you'll have access to all of WP inside `wpse_60353_autosearch`, without having to point to an external file & *dirtily* loading WP with something like `require '../../../wp-load.php` (or similar).

---

**Update**: Firstly, I would strongly advise to use something like [typewatch](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) - using `onkeyup` will fire a request far too often for what you need; it'll annoy the user not to mention overload the server.

Secondly, I've noticed an error in your query:

```
$args = array( 'post__in='.$mypostids ); // This concats your IDs array to a string
$args = array( 'post__in' => $mypostids ); // See the difference?
```

In fact, I would rewrite it to use the initial result - saves querying & should lighten things up:

```
isset( $_POST['autoSearch'] ) && add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_60353_autosearch' );
function wpse_60353_autosearch()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = like_escape( $_POST['autoSearch'] );
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE
            post_status = 'publish' AND
            post_title LIKE %s AND
            post_type IN ( 'post', 'page' )
        ORDER BY
            post_date DESC
        LIMIT 5",

        "%$query%"
    ));

    // update_post_caches( &$posts, $post_type, $update_term_cache, $update_meta_cache )
    update_post_caches( $posts, 'post', false, true );

    $titles = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
        $titles[] = get_the_title( $post->ID );

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
    echo json_encode( array( 'everything' => implode( '<br />', $titles ) ) );
    exit;
}
```

And for your JS:

```
function autoSearch( link )
{
    var $results = $( "#searchResults" ).width( $( "#searchArea" ).width() ), s = $( "#searchField" ).val();
    if ( s != "" ) {
        $.post( link, { autoSearch: s }, function ( data ) {
            $results.show().html( data.everything );
        }, "json" );
    } else {
        $results.hide();
    }
}
```

Note that I have tested this code on my own install & can confirm it functions as expected: typing a search term displays a maximum of 5 found titles, otherwise the results div is hidden if no results.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm trying to see if I have this right:$.post("<?php echo esc_js( site_url() ) ?>" + "autoSearch.php",{autoSearch:"yeah", value:$("#searchField").val()},function(data){
   $("#searchResults").show();
   $("#searchResults").html(data.everything);
  },"json");

Comment: No no, you don't need to append `autoSearch.php`, just need the site URL - the PHP code will intercept the default request & echo your data.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't give me a return. I got two messages. A 200 on a GET request and a 301 on a POST request with a "Permanently Moved" error.

Comment: Update your question with the code you're now currently using.

Comment: Ok. I seriously appreciate this help!

Comment: I just updated the post.

Comment: Check out my update.

Comment: It's not returning any data for me. This is incredibly strange.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4353/discussion-between-majed-and-thedeadmedic)

Comment: Well, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Majed I don't want to appear rude, but I feel I've spent more than enough time assisting you. Responding with "it's not returning data for me" is like saying "it doesn't work, fix it for me". Show me *your* efforts - have you tried debugging? Can you isolate the problem? What else have you tried?

Comment: I've actually tried to see what the issue is. I've looked up the errors through the debugging tool in Safari. I got a Get response 200, which means that was working, however because it was a GET response, it hasn't retrieved the data. I then saw a POST response, and I got a 301 ERROR. I looked up on google and it said that it was moved permanently believing the URL to be of another source. Since being new to wordpress I have no idea what that means. I tried debugging this whole thing almost the whole day yesterday, and I didn't get anywhere. I'm sorry it appeared that way, but I really tried.

Comment: The AJAX POST shouldn't result in a 301 - try `site_url( '/' )` instead (will append a trailing slash).